# How to have distinct signal for clicking outside of dialog?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a dialog with 'YES' and 'NO' buttons. and I'd like pressing outside of dialog just close the dialog and doesn't trigger 'NO' button signal too (just pressing 'NO' button should trigger it). is it possible?

```
Dialog {
    id: dialog
    title: "Save your Info?"
    width: parent.width/2
    modal: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
    standardButtons: Dialog.Yes | Dialog.No

    onAccepted: console.log("Yes clicked")
    onRejected: console.log("No clicked")
    onClosed: console.log("Dialog closed")
    Component.onCompleted: open()
}
```

now, if i click outside of dialog, it prints:

> *qml: No clicked*
>
> *qml: Dialog closed*

Is it possible that just close dialog by clicking outside of it(actually cancel it) and NOT reject it too before closing?

**update:** Actually i just wanted to have 3 distinct signals for 'Yes' and 'No' and 'Cancel' by clicking outside

Answer (score 0):

Change modality to `false` (so that you can press outside while closePolicy is NOT `CloseOnPressOutside` a modal dialog will block your presses), change `closePolicy` to anything else (not `CloseOnPressOutside`) but don't leave it default. Add `MouseArea` to handle pressing outside dialog.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Close dialog my marea")
    Dialog {
        id: dialog
        title: "Title"
        width: parent.width/2
        modal: false
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnReleaseOutsideParent // something I never use
        standardButtons: Dialog.Yes | Dialog.No
        onAccepted: console.log("Yes clicked")
        onRejected: console.log("No clicked")
        onClosed: console.log("Dialog closed")
        Component.onCompleted: open()

    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            dialog.close()

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for your response mohammad. but i tried more to find a better way, and finally i found this approach. i hope it help others too.

```
Dialog {
    id: dialog
    title: "Title"
    width: parent.width/2
    modal: true
    closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
    footer: DialogButtonBox {
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Yes")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.AcceptRole
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("No")
            DialogButtonBox.buttonRole: DialogButtonBox.DestructiveRole
        }
    }

    onAccepted: console.log("Yes Btn clicked")
    onRejected: console.log("Dialog closed")
    onDiscarded: {
        console.log("No Btn clicked")
        close()
    }

    Component.onCompleted: open()
}
```

Comment: No this code doesn't provide what you want .. . according to your answer .. when "No" is pressed the dialog is _destructed_ (not rejected) .. while still when press outside the dialog is still "Rejected" .. this not what you asked for .. nor a good way of pop up a dialog.

Comment: Also answer code is confusing words .. first the "No" button should be associated with reject role `DialogButtonBox.RejectRole` not as `DialogButtonBox.DestructiveRole` .. *this is your requirement in question!* Second: `onRejected: console.log("Dialog closed")` is wrong .. it should be `onRejected: console.log("No Btn clicked")` .. this code *does not meet question requirement* and using tricky messages.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps you right and my question hadn't enough comments, actually i just wanted to have 3 distinct signals for 'Yes' and 'No' and 'Cancel' by clicking outside.

Comment: You didn't update your question and your solution doesn't work for both scenarios .. regardless of number of buttons .. pressing outside will call reject role.